# TypeScript definition file for JavaScript class without having to declare all members

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a typescript definition for a big JavaScript class without adding all its members, I would like it to be of type "any". For example:

ContainerSurface.d.ts:

```
declare class ContainerSurface {
}
export = ContainerSurface;
```

And just use the class and call any members on it without having them "declared", like:

MyClass.ts:

```
import ContainerSurface = require('ContainerSurface');

class MyClass extends ContainerSurface {
    constructor(options) {
        super(options);
        var a: ContainerSurface({option: "test"});
        a.add("test");
    }
}

export = MyClass;
```

Comment: Why have a class if you're not going to give it an interface? This pretty much goes against what TypeScript is all about.

Comment: If you want to use a javascript library (in our case famo.us), but don't have the time and knowledge to generate .d.ts files for it, and need to inherit using typescript from a javascript class you want this... believe me...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following:

```
declare var ContainerSurface: any;

export = ContainerSurface;
```

This is the first step in my [Definition Files Made Easy](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/) process - so you can gradually add types over time using this as the starting point.

Step two is to loosely specify properties and methods:

```
declare class ContainerSurface {
    myMethod: any;
    myProperty: any;
}

export = ContainerSurface;
```

Grab any quick wins, like primitive types, and just add the stuff you actually use to start off with.

Comment: This didn't work for me... I'm using AMD modules, could it be that this is the problem? It works for me the way I described, but then I must include all functions I call. Using your approach I get the error: "super can only be referenced in a derived class', 'extends of exported class '...' has or is using private name '...'.

Comment: You can't extend `any`. You'll have to supply more type information if you want to use inheritance, but you can do it gradually as per the article I linked.

Comment: I did this in my current code base, I declared: declare class ContainerSurface { prototype(opts:any); add(s:string); } export = ContainerSurface; But what if there are a whole set of other functions, but that I don't want to declare them (for example del(), prev(), next()), is there a way to do this, or should I declare all functions that I actually use?

Comment: Each property you need to access can be declared on the class as `any` until you are ready to add more precise definitions. i.e. `myMethod : any;`